# Transform dates with $project in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am getting an error when I try to reshape the dates field in my collection.

This is the schema and I would like to reshape the `sent` field which holds the dates:

```js
> db.complaints.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e5990d991312e2c9b266e3"),
    "complaintID" : 1388734,
    "product" : "mortgage",
    "subProduct" : "conventional adjustable mortgage (arm)",
    "issue" : "loan servicing, payments, escrow account",
    "subIssue" : "",
    "state" : "va",
    "ZIP" : 22204,
    "submitted" : "web",
    "received" : "2015-05-22",
    "sent" : "2015-05-22",
    "company" : "green tree servicing, llc",
    "response" : "closed with explanation",
    "timely" : "yes",
    "disputed" : ""
}
```

This is the query and the error message I am getting:

```js
db.complaints.aggregate([
{$project:
    {_id:0, 
    sent: 1, 
    Year:{$year:"$sent"},
    Month: {$month:"$sent"}, 
    Day: {$dayOfMonth: "$sent"}, 
    product : 1}},

])
> db.complaints.aggregate([
... {$project:
... {_id:0,
... sent: 1,
... Year:{$year:"$sent"},
... Month: {$month:"$sent"},
... Day: {$dayOfMonth: "$sent"},
... product : 1}},
...
... ])
assert: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type String to Date",
    "code" : 16006,
    "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
Error: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type String to Date",
    "code" : 16006,
    "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
at Error (<anonymous>)
at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:254:5)
at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1278:12)
at (shell):1:15
2015-09-12T13:16:22.876+0100 E QUERY    Error: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type String to Date",
    "code" : 16006,
    "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
at Error (<anonymous>)
at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:254:5)
at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1278:12)
at (shell):1:15 at src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13
> db.complaints.aggregate([
... {$project:
... {_id:0,
... sent: 1,
... Year:{$year:"$sent"},
... Month: {$month:"$sent"},
... Day: {$dayOfMonth: "$sent"},
... product : 1}},
...
... ])
assert: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type String to Date",
    "code" : 16006,
    "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
Error: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type String to Date",
    "code" : 16006,
    "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
at Error (<anonymous>)
at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:254:5)
at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1278:12)
at (shell):1:15
2015-09-12T13:21:08.767+0100 E QUERY    Error: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type String to Date",
    "code" : 16006,
    "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
at Error (<anonymous>)
at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:254:5)
at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1278:12)
at (shell):1:15 at src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13
>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use the date operators like `$year` with values that have a BSON Date data type. Your `sent` field's value is a string, so you'd need to use [`$substr`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/#exp._S_substr) to split the date string by position instead:

```javascript
db.complaints.aggregate([
{$project:
    {_id: 0, 
    sent: 1, 
    Year: {$substr: ["$sent", 0, 4]},
    Month: {$substr: ["$sent", 5, 2]}, 
    Day: {$substr: ["$sent", 8, 2]}, 
    product: 1}}
])
```

Result:

```javascript
{
"product" : "mortgage",
"sent" : "2015-05-22",
"Year" : "2015",
"Month" : "05",
"Day" : "22"
}
```

Comment: will that convert dates in all the collection?

Comment: @tottihope It won't convert them, but it will transform the output as you described.

Comment: Thank you very much JohnnyHK. It does the string conversion to date as it reshapes the documents.